# Data sets without services SOAP or REST?

Tags: soapui

I wonder if it is possible to create test cases or test model, managed with soapUI.
Without SOAP web services or REST available, just with post / get request.
And apply data sets with an excel file for example.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a testStep 'http' which can be used to consume http services with post and get.
I use it for post / XML and almost all feature work fine.
I met some difficulties with the mock services feature as it is designed to mock soap services, but you can overcome the issues quite easily.

I use a lot the datasource testep combined with the datasource loop teststep which are great to loop over data from an external source (excel, database...).